# How does child_process behave in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have a working Nodejs code, however, the child_process library behaves strange, I am just wondering how this library works.

My code is trying to download the SSL certificates from S3, then create the two new files based on the exiting ones using child_process library.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const child_process = require("child_process");
const exec = require('child_process').exec; 

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var filePath = '../Desktop/Certs/'
var bucketName = 'neb.certificates' //replace example bucket with your s3 bucket name

var params = {
    Bucket: bucketName, 
    Prefix: 'dev/jenkins.secure.care/',
  };

  s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {
        // console.log(data.Contents)
        var len = data.Contents.length

        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            var key = data.Contents[i]["Key"]

            var newPath = filePath.concat(key.substring(31))

            const downloadFile = (newPath, bucketName, key) => {

                //construct getParam
                var getParams = {
                    Bucket: bucketName,
                    Key: key
                };

                s3.getObject(getParams, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) console.error(err)
                    fs.writeFileSync(newPath, data.Body.toString())
                    // console.log(`${newPath} has been created!`)
                })
            }

            downloadFile(newPath, bucketName, key)
        }
    }
  });

  exec('mv  ../Desktop/Certs/cert.pem ../Desktop/Certs/jenkins.crt', (err, stdout, stderr) => {  
    if (err) {  
      console.error(err);  
      return;  
    }  
    console.log(stdout);  
  }); 

  exec('mv ../Desktop/Certs/privkey.pem ../Desktop/Certs/jenkins.key', (err, stdout, stderr) => {  
    if (err) {  
      console.error(err);  
      return;  
    }  
    console.log(stdout);  
  });
```

So when I run the code the first time, it only downloads the certificates from S3 to the local folder, it did not create the other 2 files. Then I have to run it the second time to create additional files.

However, I just want to run it once, and it has everything what I expect.

I have added a code which to sleep 5 seconds, then create the additional files, But it did not solve my problem, which means I still run the code twice to get everything.

```
child_process.execSync("sleep 5");
```

Please helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is the async execution of your code. In this example here's what's happening:

1. Run `s3.listObjectsV2()` and *when finished*, fire callback (but not now, *in the future*)
2. Run first `exec()` and *when finished*, fire callback (but not now, *in the future*)
3. Run second `exec()` and *when finished*, fire callback (but not now, *in the future*)

And those three steps are fired immediately, one by one. And each of them has its own callback which fires *in the future*. Ok, but when is the *future*? - exactly! You don't know. In your case probably those two callbacks in `exec()`'s are fired before the callback from `s3` and this is why it does not work.

The solution here is to make sure that those `exec()`s are fired after `s3.listObjects`. So you have two options: first is to make a promise out of the `s3`, like this: `s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise()` and `await` for it, then in `.then((data) => {})` you have your `data` and in `.catch((error) => {})` you have your `error`. Or you can simply put those `exec()`s in the callback of the `s3` call.

---

Your code should look like this according to the solution 2 (from the comments):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const child_process = require("child_process");
const exec = require('child_process').exec; 

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var filePath = '../Desktop/Certs/'
var bucketName = 'neb.certificates' //replace example bucket with your s3 bucket name

var params = {
  Bucket: bucketName, 
  Prefix: 'dev/jenkins.secure.care/',
};

s3.listObjectsV2(params, async function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else {
      // console.log(data.Contents)
      var len = data.Contents.length

      for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
          var key = data.Contents[i]["Key"]

          var newPath = filePath.concat(key.substring(31))

          const downloadFile = (newPath, bucketName, key) => {

              //construct getParam
              var getParams = {
                  Bucket: bucketName,
                  Key: key
              };
              return s3.getObject(getParams).promise();
          };

          const downloadData = await downloadFile(newPath, bucketName, key).catch(console.error);
          fs.writeFileSync(newPath, downloadData.Body.toString());
          console.log(newPath, 'created');
      }

      //rename files
      console.log('renaming first cert.pem');
      exec('mv  ../Desktop/Certs/cert.pem ../Desktop/Certs/jenkins.crt', (err, stdout, stderr) => {  
        if (err) {  
          console.error(err);  
          return;  
        }  
        console.log(stdout);  
      }); 

      console.log('renaming second privkey.pem');
      exec('mv ../Desktop/Certs/privkey.pem ../Desktop/Certs/jenkins.key', (err, stdout, stderr) => {  
        if (err) {  
          console.error(err);  
          return;  
        }  
        console.log(stdout);  
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I am very new to the Nodejs, and I think I prefer putting those `exec()` in the callback function, the question is that where do I need to put the callback function. Under this line `downloadFile(newPath, bucketName, key)` is a good idea?

Comment: You need to put those `exec`s under this line: `fs.writeFileSync(newPath, data.Body.toString())`, because this is where you are done downloading the files from the s3 and are able to operate on them (like renaming e.x.)

Comment: I still have a hard time to implement the callback in my code :(

Comment: I add the `callback` as the optional argument in the function, which look like this ```const downloadFile = (newPath, bucketName, key, callback)``` I have no idea how to put 2 callbacks in the call

Comment: I just tried your updated solution, it is still not working in my case :(

Comment: What is the exact output of a single run of updated code? Can you post it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191477/discussion-between-akira-and-sebastian-kaczmarek).